# Can a triplet be a qutrit?

Tags: unitarity, quantum-state

### Original question

A triplet is a space that consist of three states that have the same total angular momentum (spin 1). If we restrict ourselves to a set of quantum gates that keep triplet states in that space, what are the limitations for doing computation?

As I understand it, a triplet is not enough for a qutrit. Qutrit operations would be in U(3) which is larger than the triplet-preserving space(?). Apparently, some unitary gates in U(3) would send a triplet state outside the triplet basis. So implicitly my question is what is that triplet space and whether any meaningful computation can be done with just triplet-preserving gates?

The generators of rotations (angular momenta $L_x,L_y,L_z$) for spin 1 are already not-unitary  see the matrices here [Confusion about rotations of quantum states: (3) versus (2) - PSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/394152/confusion-about-rotations-of-quantum-states-so3-versus-su2). But I guess that’s not important as the [generators of SU(3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices) are not unitary either.

### Revised question

After more research I am wondering triplet$=$qutrit. I thought of that not being the case because I thought angular momentum algebra on triplets was not unitary, suggesting I could generalize the $L_x,L_y,L_z$ as gates, the same way that is done with 2-level systems. Yet to generate SU(3), the generators cannot work as gates either.

Also any unitary operation in this space would just create a linear combination of triplets, that conserve total spin 1. So can I use the states of a triplet as a qutrit or am I missing something?

Comment: Is it true that a superposition of two triplet states is in general not a triplet?

Comment: @NikitaNemkov I won't see why would that be so. A superposition of triplet is still a triplet in the sense that conserves $L^2$ (but does not conserve $L_z$).

Comment: OK, so then you have three-dimensional Hilbert space of triplet states, why wouldn't that be a qutrit?

Comment: @NikitaNemkov that’s why I changed my question, I have heard that it is not several times but I have failed to find a good reason by now

Comment: I think you still have to make a question more precise for it to be well-posed. As you observe, a "triplet" is a three-dimensional space. This is what I'd define as a qutrit. Unless you have some other definition of "qutrit" in mind? If so, what is it? The group of unitaries acting on the triplet space could be characterised as those unitaries that preserve the singlet, so $I\otimes U(3)$, which is isomorphic to $U(3)$. The corresponding generators (i.e. its Lie algebra) would then also be the standard angular momentum operators. I'm not sure what you mean with "cannot work as gates"

Comment: @glS for qubits, the corresponding angular momentum generators are Pauli matrices, which can be by themselves gates. You can apply $S_z=Z$ to a qubit, but you have to be careful applying $L_z$ to a triplet/qutrit. Pauli $Z$ is unitary while $L_z$ is not.

Comment: generators of unitaries are (skew-)Hermitian matrices, which are not in general unitary, sure, and thus cannot be deterministically applied to states as gates. But why do you want to be able to apply the generators as gates? And why does this affect whether something is a qutrit or not?

Comment: @glS it was a misconception that’s all. Also at least Pauli matrices work as gates for qubits. I guess the usual argument against triplets is physical (as angular momentum operations is not exactly what you need) and not theoretical, see : [Quantum systems: three-level vs qutrit - PSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/342903/quantum-systems-three-level-vs-qutrit)

Comment: yes, Pauli matrices are a bit of a coincidence I'd say. They are a basis for the linear space of Hermitian 2x2 matrices, which also happen to be unitary. But also note that arbitrary 2x2 unitaries are generated by *linear combinations* of Paulis, and these combinations are not in general unitary themselves, so your objection holds even for qubits.

Comment: About the difference: I'd say "qutrit" is a generic three-level system. A "three level atomic system" has more physics built in, in that you assume atoms to behave in specific ways. I'm not so sure you can't call "qutrit" a system even if you can't perform arbitrary operations on it, though. I don't think I've seen such a definition anywhere. People call "qudits" systems in which they can only perform some types of operations all the time (as also pointed out in the comment of the answer you link)